# How to get the name of an asset with a cloudkit query

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am using cloudkit to store images and my app queries the images. I want to save storage space by using the image file name to populate a label in my app, instead of an additional string record with the title. 
Is it possible to pull the asset name as a string?

something like...

```
self.pred = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Images", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        self.queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive
        self.queryOperation = CKQueryOperation (query: query)
        self.queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {
            record in

            let Image = record.objectForKey("Image")! as! CKAsset
            imageLabel.text = Image.recordName as! NSString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fileURL` property of the `CKAsset`. Then get the `filename` from the `NSURL`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using: Image.fileURL.URLByDeletingPathExtension!.lastPathComponent, but I get something like: 
4CE2AE91-7078-431A-B2EB-xxxxxxxxx

Comment: That seems right. You can't count on the asset's URL being anything like the original URL used to create the asset. CloudKit generated some GUID to ensure the filename is unique. Basically this means you can't do what you hoped. You are going to need to add some sort of "name" field to your "Images" record.

Comment: Dang, that is what I was hoping to avoid. I guess it isn't possible. Thank you!